# selector not working with layout and image view

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I want to use selector for a layout and image view..But it is not working for me.
When I changed image view to imagebutton or button, it works fine. Any help will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance..

here is the xmls I used..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg" 
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_01" />
</selector>
```

The layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="layout tester"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/testselector"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what is your exact problem...?

Comment: I think layout does not support selector(I am not sure). Better try shape property.Why you going for selector?

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I ran into this problem just now.  You'll have to set the LinearLayout to clickable.  You can either do this in the XML with

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or in code with

```
yourLinearLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Awesome :) had this problem bugging me :)

Comment: PERFECT! I was going through this for two hours, this did it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
    <selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/lastread_ok" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/lastread_ok" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/lastread_ok_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lastread_ok" />
</selector>
```

you can use your image instead of `lastread_ok` & l`astread_ok_selected`

Answer (score 1):

use the id of imageview instead of linear layout and setclicklistener for imageview itself, it will work!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `src` to `background`

or

`ImageButton` to `ImageView` and alse write `android:clickable="true"`in ImageView attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to not assign the attribute `android:clickable` to the layout but to the ImageView instead. I just wanted the image to be clickable though, not the containing layout.

Answer (score 0):

setOnClickListener() for selectable components solved the problem